# Email alert vs invocable apex

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I'm trying to understand what are the benefits of using invocable actions called by Process Builder comparing to Process Builder + Flow. In what scenario invocable actions are preferable?

Answer (score 3):

Flows are simple to use, but limited in what they can do. Invocable actions require writing code, but have virtually unlimited potential compared to flows. Use flows for simple tasks that don't require code, and use invocable actions when flows simply won't cut it.